# Passing variables in Task.Factory

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to pass a few variables to my thread action using `Task.Factory.StartNew();`.
This is example code:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string source = webClient.DownloadString("http://localhost/?search=" + search_string);
        return source;
    })
.ContinueWith(result =>
    {
        search_string = search.Text;
        search_string = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(search_string, Encoding.UTF8).Replace("+", "%20");
    });
```

What I want is to pass a groupbox and a panel into the ContinueWith() method, so I can add search results to the panel.

Answer (score 3):

You don’t need to “pass” your UI elements into your `ContinueWith` method; capturing local variables or even accessing instance variables directly is fine.

However, you do need to ensure that your `ContinueWith` delegate executes on the UI thread. You may achieve this simply by using [an overload that takes a `TaskScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321307), specifying the scheduler returned by [`FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.fromcurrentsynchronizationcontext.aspx):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        string source = webClient.DownloadString(
            "http://localhost/?search=" + search_string);
        return source;
    })
.ContinueWith(antecedent =>
    {
        // Example use of result:
        this.resultTextBox.Result = antecedent.Result;
    },
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Don’t forget that the parameter passed to the `ContinueWith` delegate is the antecedent *task*, not its result. To retrieve the result, use its [`Result`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468) property.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need not pass them. You can simply reference them within the lambda function. Note that you have to use Invoke or a Dispatcher to access UI elements from a different thread.

Every variable that is "shared" between different lambda functions must be declared *outside* the lambda function (closure!!!!).

Comment: window.Invoke (someDelegate); , with someDelegate being a (delegate to) a function that does what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass variables (controls) into the continuation; just access them normally in the continuation code.

But when the thread accesses the controls, you'll get cross-thread exceptions. To prevent that, run the continuation on the UI thread:

```
.ContinueWith(result => 
    { 
        search_string = search.Text; 
        search_string = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(search_string, Encoding.UTF8).Replace("+", "%20"); 
        // update the UI here (result.Result will contain the return value from the task)        
    }, 
    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Passing `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` ensures the continuation is dispatched back to the main thread.